# Minimum number of states in a DFA

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Consider the language L given by the regular expression (a + b )*b(a + b) over the alphabet {a, b} . The smallest
number of states needed in a deterministic finite-state automaton (DFA) accepting L is :

My attempt :
I designed the following DFA
[image: My DFA for the language]

The answer key says that minimal DFA will have 4 states. I am unable to find a counterexample for my DFA. So where am I going wrong?

Comment: The word $bbb$ is not accepted by your automaton.

Comment: Okay got it, thanks!!